# Magnto 2 update the cart custom option value

Tags: magento2, custom-options, upgrade, addtocart, quoteitem

Currently am using magento 2.2.5,

while adding the product to the cart the custom options values are stored in the `quote_item_option` table correctly.

while updating the custom options programmatically it has not changed in the `quote_item_option` table and doesn't throw any exception.

Please guide me with the proper solutions.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to set the custom options and to change them programatically?

Comment: @HelgeB I have posted the codes into the github. Please find the link below
https://github.com/thilaRathin/magento2/

Comment: @HelgeB this link is not active now. can you please share it again, the code.

Comment: @HelgeB link is not active. Can you share it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding what exactly you want to achieve with your change of option value: If you just want to modify the value of an already set option, I guess you can simplify your code in `_saveCartItemEngravingOptionValue`.

Remove the line `$cartItem->setOptions($options)->save();` (the option is already in the cart item) and just call save on the specific option object:

```
$option->setValue(...)->save();
```

That should save the changes if you get into that part of the code (I would suggest to add some logging to your code, to see if that is the case).

Comment: Thanks you so much man.. its working fine

Comment: how can i get $option for cart item?

Answer (score 2):

create an observer using checkout_cart_product_add_after event into Vender/CustomModule/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
 <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="change_custom_option" instance="Vender\CustomModule\Observer\ChangeCustomOption" />
 </event>
```

then create observer into Vender\CustomModule\Observer/ChangeCustomOption.php

```
  use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

  class ChangeCustomOption implements ObserverInterface
   {
     public function execute(Observer $observer) {

       $item  = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');          
       $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

       $_product = $item->getProduct();

       $options  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_product);

       $customOptions = $options['options'];

       $customValue  = 10.6; //fill value here

       foreach($customOptions as $key=>$option): 

          if($option[label]==Size):
               $item->getOptionByCode('option_'.$option['option_id'])->setValue($customValue);
          endif;

       endforeach;     
    }
 }
```

hope it will help you.

Happy Coding!